# An internal server error has occurred

Tags: gack

I don't know why, but I am getting this error a lot times for the past couple of hours.

**An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.**

I basically have developed CRM functionality by writing Visualforce pages and Apex controllers and I also made few web service calls (getting data from external application).

Whenever, I try to delete a contact record or try to create a New Task or open an Account record, I get this type of error And when I check the debug logs, it doesn't include where my controller has stopped working.

```
28.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO 
02:56:39.026 (26123456)|EXECUTION_STARTED
02:56:39.026 (26166981)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|066G0000001uKmF|VF: /apex/    ContactView_VF
02:56:39.027 (27139570)|VF_DESERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN|066G0000001uKmF
02:56:39.397 (73921518)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
02:56:39.397|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
Number of callouts: 0 out of 10
Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
Number of future calls: 0 out of 10
Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

02:56:39.397|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

02:56:39.073 (73979373)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/ContactView_VF
02:56:39.075 (75410639)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Is there a way to resolve this and more importantly, what could possibly causing this to occur.

Comment: Without any information on where and when this is happening, or what code might be involved it's really hard to make a guess or expect anyone to answer this. Please understand that when asking a question more details related (!) to the issue help others to analyse and answer. Help us help you.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The message states what you could or should do:

> If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in
>   reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce
>   Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any
>   error id shown on this page as well as any other related information.
>   We apologize for the inconvenience.

Internal server errors indicate something unexpected happen which may be the result of a bug or malfunction in the salesforce system. This also means that there's probably nothing you can do to solve this, and that it may not be related to anything specific you're doing.

Comment: Based on my experience, there's at least one case in which you can do something : I got this error while uploading a package, and I solved by recompiling all classes and trying to upload again my package, and it worked for me (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008pTRIAY)

Comment: @Samuel I also raised a case with Salesforce and they have responded saying:

**Developer support is currently available only to our premier customers and Premier partners. We apologize for any impact this may be having on you.

We support our standard customers through the developer support boards at https://developer.salesforce.com/.

If you have a developer support question, are looking for technical documentation, best practices, code samples and other ways to speed your development time. We have dedicated support representatives that work the boards to answer questions.**

Comment: Ok, than I suggest you do include full details of when this is happenning to see if we can replicate this. By updating your question.

Comment: @ToninoTripodiI am getting this error in my Sandbox Org where I customized CRM functionality. Like, when I am trying to delete a Contact record or view an Account record, then I am getting this error. By looking at your referral link, it is told that this occurs during packaging, but mine is a different case. However, I would give a try for what is mentioned in the solution.

Comment: @Sapthagiri , I understand, and I think it's not useful to give a try for what is mentioned, because your problem  is completely different. Is there any ERROR ID?

Comment: @ToninoTripodi **Error ID: 1527290679-4722 (1792053171)** is what I get when I try deleting a Contact. And I just notice that I am getting the following error when trying to create a New Task : **java.security.ProviderException: doFinal() failed**

Comment: The issue could be related to the webservices call you set up. I wouldtry debugging by removing them.

Comment: @ToninoTripodi I couldn't get much of help while debugging and hence I have refreshed my Sandbox account.